# WCF -> ASMX and Cookies

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have a web application that communicates to a WCF service through a WCF client. At the point my code is invoked, authentication cookies have been issued and I have a dependency on an ASMX service that expects those authentication cookies.

I need to pass the cookies from the web application through the WCF client to the WCF service to the ASMX service.

Any ideas? It looks like my best bet may be setting allowCookies to false, parsing out the cookie headers, attempting to re-create them on the WCF service and then attaching them to the SOAP request.

Note: I looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201153/wcf-client-consuming-multiple-asmx-service-that-uses-http-cookies), which seems close but not quite applicable to this question. In the linked scenario, an ASMX service is creating cookies, which must be persisted to a subsequent ASMX service by the same WCF client.

Comment: Who is issuing the authentication cookies?  Does your WCF service use the cookies or is it a pass-through?

Comment: Cookies are issued by another web application. The WCF service does not use the cookies, but needs to pass them through to the ASMX service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so there's two main things that need to occur:

1. Get the cookie from the web app context to the WCF service
2. Get the cookie from the WCF service to the ASMX service

**NOTE:** Because you didn't specify, I'm going to *assume* that you're using a WCF client within your WCF service to talk to the ASMX service. If this is not the case please let me know and I will revise this post accordingly.

**Step #1:**

I would recommend writing an [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) which you bind to your client endpoints using an [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx). In your implementation of [IClientMessageInspector::BeforeSendRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest.aspx) you basically read the cookie out of the current HttpContext::Request::Cookies collection and append the value as a message header. That would look a little something like this:

```
public void BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    // Get the cookie from ASP.NET
    string cookieValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookieName"].Value;   

    // Create a header that represents the cookie
    MessageHeader myCookieNameHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("MyCookieHeaderName", "urn:my-custom-namespace", cookieValue);   

    // Add the header to the message
    request.Headers.Add(myCookieNameHeader);
}
```

One you configure the endpoint with this message inspector every logical request will automatically flow the cookie value through as a header to your WCF service. Now, since your WCF service doesn't actually care about the header itself, it can basically ignore it. In fact, if you only did this step, you should be able to run all your code right now and not experience any difference.

**Step #2:**

Now we need the cookie to go from the WCF service to the ASMX service. Once again all you need to do is implement an [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx), except your BeforeSendMessageRequest is going to be a little different:

```
public void BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    // Get the cookie value from the custom header we sent in from step #1
    string cookieValue = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("MyCookieHeaderName", "urn:my-custom-namespace");

    HttpRequestMessageHeaderProeperty httpRequestMessageHeaderProperty;
    MessageProperties outgoingMessageProperties = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties;

    // Get the HttpRequestMessageHeaderProperty, if it doesn't already exist we create it now
    if(!outgoingMessageProperties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageHeaderProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageHeaderProperty))
    {
        httpRequestmessageHeaderProperty = new HttpRequestMessageHeaderProperty();

        outgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageHeaderProperty.Name, httpRequestmessageHeaderProperty);
    }

    // Set the cookie header to our cookie value (note: sample assumes no other cookies set)
    httpRequestmessageHeaderProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = cookieValue;
}
```

Once again you need to bind this to the endpoint for your ASMX service using an [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx) and every logical request you make will automatically pass the cookie through.

Comment: [Drew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/185859/drew-marsh), how would you revise this if the client is a JavaScript JSON call?

Comment: @dumbledad There are a couple clients in the scenario above. There's the web application client calling from the browser, the web page calling the WCF service and then the WCF service calling ASMX service. I'm assuming you're referring to the web application call being a JavaScript call instead of a post back?

Comment: [@Drew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/185859/drew-marsh) it feels odd to me that I can read from a HTTP cookie in WCF with  WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] but writing to the cookie needs a message inspector, but I'll try to formulate this fully as a question and post it separately

Comment: @dumbledad It doesn't _require_ a message inspector. I recommended it because the OP appeared to just want the cookies ubiquitously copied across and to centralize that logic in one place it makes the most sense to use a message inspector. You can of course write cookies using the context's OutgoingRequest/Response::Headers directly.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I'm stuck doing just that, and so I've formulated a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10014432/575530).