# Adding Cookie in asmx not working

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery, asmx, httpcookie

I have a asmx webservice which has a webmethod that I'm calling it via jquery ajax and it returns a string, I want to read and edit cookies from this method, I know that I can read the cookie like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie["cookie_name"];
```

but when I'm trying to change the value of this cookie, this doesn't work:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie["cookie_name"].Value = "some_value";
```

so let's say this is my function:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string myMethod()
{
    //...some actions 
    if(HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie["cookie_name"] != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie["cookie_name"].Value = "some_value";
    }
    return "";
}
```

and here is my ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/route-to/myMethod",
        data: JSON.stringify({ }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        charset: "utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {

        }
    });
```

What's exactly is wrong in this code?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556218/wcf-asmx-and-cookies

Comment: @SLaks as I debug the asmx method and it's fine but when I check my cookies in my browser the cookie value is still the previous value.

Comment: What response headers do you see in the network tab?

Comment: In the response headers I have the cookie set with the new value set it is supposed to but when I check my browser's cookie it is still the same previous value