# Cookies in wcf service OperationContract

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies, operationcontract

Is it possible to read cookies in the OperationContract of a wcf service? I am trying to read a cookie value in the contract method, but its always empty. If I read the same cookie from a .aspx page, the value is present. Any ideas?

Comment: Code, please. Hard to know what you're doing wrong when you don't show what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you hosting them?   WCF is intended to be host-neutral -- i.e. your services should still work when hosted outside of IIS.  However, there is a compatibilty mode which might help you:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The default value is false and disables most ASP.NET features like HttpContext.Current.

Answer (score 1):

The [BasicHttpBinding.AllowCookies Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.allowcookies.aspx) may fix this, as mentioned at the start of [Enrico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26396/enrico-campidoglio)'s blog post on [Managing shared cookies in WCF](http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/) (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381039/575530)). The post includes the web.config fragment:

```xml
<system.ServiceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding allowCookies="true">
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myservice"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.ServiceModel>
```

but no code fragment using it (the blog post has code for more complex solutions using the same cookies with different web services).

======== EDIT ==========

Or perhaps even [allowCookies=false](http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/211)